# Is it valid to have a pointer and a non pointer data type in a union?

Tags: c

Assuming we dereference correctly and use the integer right, is this a good programming practice?

```
union {
int x;
struct node * next;
};
```

Comment: `union`s are never a good programming practice.

Comment: Not a portable program atleast

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: There's absolutely nothing bad or non-portable about unions. The "non-portable" mythology is usually rooted in completely misguided belief that unions exist for memory reinterpretation purposes. This is no more than a myth. To say that "unions are never a good practice" is completely incorrect.

Comment: I said because `sizeof(int)` may not equal to `sizeof(void*)` for some plate form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unions are rather low-level language feature. There are no meaningful reason for any restrictive "good programming practices" to exist with regards to which types can reside together in a union. The purpose of union is to "multiplex" memory usage: to save space by storing several unrelated objects with non-overlapping lifetimes in the same memory region.

If that's what you need - go for it.

Unions are sometimes used for raw memory reinterpretation (AKA type-punning). This usage of unions used to be illegal, until it was formally legalized in one of the late technical corrigendums to C99 standard. While it has its uses, type-punning can indeed be seen as questionable programming practice.

Comment: +1 for: *"Storing unrelated objects with non-overlapping lifetimes in same memory region"*. It cannot be expressed any better.

Comment: "Storing unrelated objects with non-overlapping lifetimes in same memory region" --  love this.. This is exactly why im using this BTW. This code will go on a controller where memory saving is kinda key. Only think im worried about is someone dereferencing the int.Yes, its kernel code..

Answer (score 1):

Valid? Yes.

Good idea? Probably not. A pointer isn't even `sizeof(int)` on 64-bit, so this will lead to less-useful results.

Comment: How does it matter? What "useful results" would we get from it if they were the same size?

Comment: @AndreyT lazy-man's point-to-int casting? Not defending this usecase of unions (which do have a purpose however error prone they are).

Comment: That wouldn't be "casting". That would be memory reinterpretation AKA type-punning. Just don't do it. This is not the purpose of unions.

Comment: @AndreyT nothing wrong with type punning if you do it right, if you use only sized integers from `<stdint.h>` it's portable up to endianness, though doing it with pointers is not.